# How do I list all users that documents are shared with in Google Docs/Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

We have over a thousand documents that I need to verify whether they are being shared and if so with whom. There doesn't appear to be a way to list all users granted access whether internal or external. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at FlashPanel for Google Apps.  Once you scan all your assets you might be able to filter Docs (assets) as you want.

Available in the Marketplace here.

https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=14304+18345705634006699039&category=&query=flashpanel

Comment: FlashPanel shows you the title, owner, size, number of people shared with and last updated date for each document in your domain.  It will also let you edit settings, set policies and add users.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you look at General Audit Tool for Google Apps.  This is currently free (don't know about the future), and provides this and more. It can be accessed via the marketplace.
It provides individual users access to discover this, as well as domain admins an overview of all docs and sites in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2019, G Suite administrators have access to the [Drive Auditing log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696?hl=en)

> ### Step 2: Understand Drive audit log data
>
> **File visibility and sharing permissions**
>   When a user in your domain shares a file, a "User Sharing Permissions Change" event is added to the audit log.
>
> To see files that are shared with users outside of a domain, under **Visibility**, select **Shared Externally**.

Comment: That log GUI offers graphs over time of aggregated counts like External/Internal shares, Files added, Active users. How would it answer the question of listing each user granted access to any shared doc?

Comment: @Matthew You are looking at the **Reports** section. Collapse this section or scroll down and look at the **Audit log** section.

Comment: Well, the page your answer linked to instructs to "Go to Reports" (linked to open Reports) then "On the left, under Audit log, click Drive." But there is no Drive item in the Audit log list. https://admin.google.com/ac/reporting/audit/admin

Comment: @Matthew I suggest you to post a new question