# How can I produce a list of all external users, and documents shared with them?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

I'd like to audit our Google Drive, to review a list of all our documents shared to users external to our account. Ideally I'd like to see a list of external users, perhaps with a count of shared documents, then be able to drill down into a list of documents shared with that user.

There's an [old post about this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36367/how-do-i-list-all-users-that-documents-are-shared-with-in-google-docs-drive), however the Marketplace product appears to no longer exist.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I might go about this?

Could the Google Drive API be an option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all users that documents are shared with in Google Docs/Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36367/how-do-i-list-all-users-that-documents-are-shared-with-in-google-docs-drive)

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Google Drive Permissions Auditor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drive-permissions-auditor/hgmppaidmppjfpcdfehmcajkbpbnbgph) - [usage instructions](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-access/28237/)